# How do I stop the index.path.row from changing when table view is searched from the search bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, searchbar

The following works: I have a table view with items displayed from an array.
A button in each table view cell returns a bool value.

In the search bar, when I search for a cell, the index of the cell changes from it's value in the original table, which changes the `indexPath.row` and my button uses the incorrect `indexPath` when clicked.

Relevant code from my button:

```
(void)clickedButton:(UIButton*)sender {

NSLog(@"Row: %d", sender.tag);

NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
Stories *story = (Stories *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
BOOL isSaved = [story.isBookmarked boolValue];
story.isBookmarked = [NSNumber numberWithBool:!isSaved];
```

Relevant code from my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){

     [cell.button setSelected:[story.isBookmarked boolValue]];
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;

    }

else
{

         [cell.button setSelected:[story.isBookmarked boolValue]];
    cell.button.tag = indexPath.row;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexPath.row` might change based on your search results. Try this code to get the `indexPath`.

```
(void)clickedButton:(UIButton*)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    // Get the UITableViewCell which is the superview of the UITableViewCellContentView which is the superview of the UIButton
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[[button superview] superview];

    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [subListTable indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```